# Category Name not Updating

Tags: ee1, cache, categories

I seem to be having an issue where EE 1.6.8 doesn't seem to like the changes I'm making to the site.

For example. I've changed a category name from 'Contact / Careers' to 'Contact' but on the site it still shows 'Contact / Careers'. I've cleared browser & server cache, as well as EE cache and it's still doing this.

Looking in the DB shows the category is 'Contact' - So i'm a bit stumped as to where this name is still being pulled from.

Another weird thing... Is if I specify what categories to show using the `category="2"` tag, it shows 'Contact'!!!!!

What is going on?!

UPDATE:

```
{assign_variable:weblog="section"}

{embed="includes/head"}

{embed="includes/header"}

{exp:weblog:category_archive weblog="{weblog}" style="linear" show_empty="yes"}

    {categories}

        <h3><span><a href="#" title="{category_name}">{category_name}</a></span></h3>

        <div>

            <div class="tabs{category_id}">
                <ul class="subNav">
                    {exp:weblog:entries weblog="{weblog}" category="{category_id}" sort="asc"} 
                        <li><a href="#{url_title}" title="{title}">{title}</a></li>
                    {/exp:weblog:entries}
                </ul>

                {exp:weblog:entries weblog="{weblog}"  category="{category_id}"} 
                    <div id="{url_title}" class="col-container">

                        <div class="col2 left">
                            {section-left}
                        </div>

                        <div class="col2 right end">
                            {section-right}
                        </div>

                    </div>

                {/exp:weblog:entries}

            </div>

        </div>
    {/categories}

{/exp:weblog:category_archive}  

{embed="includes/footer"}
```

Comment: Show us the code!

Comment: Is it hard coded into the template? Was the category url title updated?

Comment: @RobsonSobral Code added to the original question

Comment: @Siebird The Cat ID is pulled in dynamically... But the Cat Name it's pulling through, doesn't even exist in the database... But when I hard code in a Cat ID... It pull the correct one through that is in the database

Comment: Now contemplating that this is a parse order issue. Just saw you wrote that the category_id only works when you put it in manually versus dynamically. Have you contemplated using Stash to set the category ID and then instead of {category_id} within the channel entries loop, use the Stash get? Another option: embed templates for the channel:entries loop sections?

Comment: Don't think Stash is available for EE1, Lea. :) Jason, couple of things to check: is the cache folder actually writable? Can you try manually deleting everything in that folder (not via the CP, but via FTP or something). Also, but that's a bit off topic, nesting tags like that is really bad for performance. Are the `{section-left}` and `{section-right}` snippets? And if so, what do they contain?

Comment: @lealea I don't think it is a parse order issue, because the site is working fine (Loading content and categories) but when I change the category name in the admin it just didn't update, so sounds like a cache to me.

Comment: @Low Yeah The {section-right} bits are just WYGWAM fields, and just contain texts. Tbh this was probably the second site I did in EE (Not to mention it being EE1) so I don't do things like this anymore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look here...  make sure "**[Cache Dynamic Section Queries?](http://ee1docs.com/cp/admin/weblog_administration/global_weblog_preferences.html)** " is set to "NO"

You can find this setting here in the CP:
**Admin  ›  Section Administration  ›  Global Section Preferences**

---

It's also possible that your EE cache isn't clearing for some reason so I'd suggest FTPing to the server and manually clearing the cache directories.

Comment: It looks like it wasn't clearing the cache! Deleting it through FTP solved this. Cache Dynamic Section Queries was already set to no. Thanks :)

Comment: Yeah! Sounds like the permissions on your cache directory aren't set correctly perhaps... Need help with that?

Comment: It was set to 777, and it still couldn't delete it - which was weird! Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Weird. Maybe delete and recreate the directory?

Answer (score 0):

Jason - Have a look at any .htaccess within the path of your install. This could be re-writting the urls...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the Category Name/Category URL Title has no duplicate. For example, if you have the same category name in two different category groups, that might freak it out perhaps?

e.g. if you have a recipe website, say you have a Category Group called Lunch and another called Dinner. Both could have categories called "Soup."

Comment: There is only one category group, and the category got removed then added back in so theres none with duplicate titles or url titles :(